# Using Google Sheets and Script to send multiple emails based on array of cell values

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am fairly new to excel coding mostly just simple functions and I am creating a grade book that would allow me to email parents and students about missing/low-performance assignments. I have found out how to send a single email based on a single cell value, but I am wanting to send several emails (to different parents as I update the grade book for different students) over several columns of value (which will be their grade input for each assignment.

Here is the code I have so far, but it sends an error when I try to add an array of values over serval columns and also when I try to send emails to different addresses for two or more different students.

````
  //Getting the grade
  var assignments = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("My Reports").getRange("B2");
  var value = assignments.getValue();

  if(value < 6){
    //Email trigger based on cell value
    var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("B2");
    var emailAddress = emailRange.getValue();

    //Send Email
    var message = 'Your student is either missing a graded assignment or has recieved a low grade. Please review with your student.'
    var subject = 'New Graded Assignment!'
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  }
}```

I am sending emails from sheet 1 on my spreadsheet, while the "grade book" is on the sheet my reports.
````

Answer (score 0):

#### Send email

```
function sendEmail() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var assignments = ss.getSheetByName("My Reports").getRange("B2");
  var value = assignments.getValue();
  if (value < 6) {
    var emailAddress = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("B2").getValue();
    var message = 'Your student is either missing a graded assignment or has recieved a low grade. Please review with your student.'
    var subject = 'New Graded Assignment!'
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  }
}
```

#### Send email to multiple addresses

```
function sendEmail() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var assignments = ss.getSheetByName("My Reports").getRange("B2");
  var value = assignments.getValue();
  if (value < 6) {
    var emailAddress = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("B2:B3").getValues().flat().join(",");
    var message = 'Your student is either missing a graded assignment or has recieved a low grade. Please review with your student.'
    var subject = 'New Graded Assignment!'
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I tried this code, and I still am only able to send a trigger email to one address. I've tried to include B2:B3 (I am trying to send two emails right now to test it).

Comment: Try it again....